# Preventing insert mode for specific key events in a React text editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keyboard, special-characters

I am working with a complex text editor and have a need to suppress the ability for the user to be able to type certain character combinations.

For example, if the user types alt-i (opt-i on Mac) the input switches to insert mode and presents a circumflex, and waits for the user to type another character (typically a vowel) to complete the accented character.

In certain situations, I want to be able to deny that behavior and prevent the circumflex from appearing at all.

In my React (javascript) code I have tried using `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();` on the various key events to no avail.  In all cases, it seems that the special character insert mode is already in effect.

Is there a way to prevent or cancel this insert mode through javascript?

Thanks in advance!